# Use of QUERY function to export selected information

Tags: google-sheets

I have one sheet containing all information. I want now to export some of this information into a new tab within the same spreadsheet. I want to copy just some columns.

```
=QUERY("Units!$A$2:$K$183"; "select A where K='31.12.2015'";1)
```

But I am getting the error `"NO_COLUMNA"`.

When I change the "A" to "Col1" I get the error `"NO_COLUMNK"`. And when I change "K" to "Col11" I get the error `"NO_COLUMNCol11"`.

So I have the sheet called "Units". In this sheet I have a lot of columns. I want to copy each row, in which the column contains the date "31.12.2015". And I want just to copy the column A and C to the new sheet.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=QUERY(Units!$A$2:$K$183; "select A where K = '31.12.2015' ";1)
```

This assumes the date is text format, so the essential difference is in the double quotes (lack of) around the data source.

Answer (score -1):

This is now working. But I just get one row listed. How can I display all rows where K=31.12.2015 ?
I have row 2 - 183 entries and it's just showing row 2 ( because in row 2 K=31.12.2015). But also row 5 K=31.12.2015 but this row it's not showing?